# How do i get buttons to change backcolour when I have left mouse button held down and scroll over them

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok I have a lot of buttons. I have gotten the mouse_click event to alternately change the back color  between light blue and light grey for each of them using:

```
    private void alternateColor(Control ctrl)
    {
        switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
        {
            case "LightGray":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                break;
            default:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                break;
        }
    }
    private void matrixButtonClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        alternateColor(sender as Control);              
    }
```

What I want to be able to do is change the color of buttons once for each time I hover over them and my left mouse buttons is held down. So if I hold left click, move over say 6 light grey buttons, they turn light blue etc.

I have this but its not working:

```
    private void matrixMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Control.MouseButtons == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            alternateColor(sender as Control);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: seems it should be drag and drop event instead of hover, you may print the `Control.MouseButtons` or put a break point on `if` to check that

Answer (score 1):

I think that you've misunderstood what "hover" means in this context for a start.  "Hover" doesn't mean to just have the mouse pointer over something.  It means to have the mouse pointer over something and stop still.  You're just talking about the `MouseEnter` event, not `MouseHover`.